# The phrase "extension by $X$"?

Tags: analysis

My professor used this term today, and I didn't get a chance to ask him what the heck it means. I can't find anything explicitly on the internet regarding the manner in which he used it.

for example, say we have a function $f(x)$ and a set $A$ where $f(x)$ is defined. If we say $f(x)$ is an extension by zero, we mean the function is evaluated if $x \in A$ and is $0$ if $x \notin A$?

Is extension by zero, in this case, saying the same thing as extension by $A?$ Furthermore, if I was to say an extension by another set $B$ with $B \cap A = \emptyset$, would I be saying $f(x)$ evaluated if $x \in B$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: Nothing you have described fits any meaning I've encountered before, and really doesn't make sense to me as described. Extensions of functions is something used all the time, but there is no such standard terminology. Extensions must either be carefully defined when they need definite values, or can be a reference to an arbitrary function extending the original, though usually subject to some limitations (for instance being continuous).

Comment: One can extend a function "to" a set - increasing its domain to include the set - but not "by" a set. I suppose someone might say "extend by 0" to mean defining the function to be 0 everywhere in so extended domain, though the domain to which it is being extended needs to be made clear in some way.